# UIImage converted in UIImageView at runtime?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, uiimage, data-conversion

I've got a view controller that accesses the contacts list and takes name, surname and the image of the contact touched by user. In shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson method:

```
if (ABPersonHasImageData(person)) {
    _imageContact = [UIImage imageWithData:(__bridge NSData *)ABPersonCopyImageData(person)];
}
```

Where variablea is declared in this way in the View Controller .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic) UIImage *imageContact;
```

I need to pass this data to another view controller that has to display them in two textfields (name and surname) and in an ImageView. So, in the prepareForSegue method I have:

```
NuovoGiocatoreViewController *ngvc = [segue destinationViewController];
ngvc.newImageFromContact = _imageContact;
```

And in NuovoGiocatoreViewController.h:

```
@property (nonatomic) UIImage *newImageFromContact;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
```

Finally in viewDidLoadMethod of the NuovoGiocatoreViewController.m file I have:

```
    _imageView.image = _newImageFromContact;
```

The application crashes with error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x112a3ea60'

Why it happens? In the debugger I notice that before the instruction  `'_imageView.image = _newImageFromContact;'` the variable
  `_newImageFromContact`has type UIImageView and not, as expected, UIImage.

Comment: Your title is strange because the runtime runs on the device or the simulator and not in Xcode. Xcode is just an IDE.

Comment: You're perfectly right. I'll remove it. Any ideas for the misterious conversion?

Comment: What is the type of `imageContact` after the line `_imageContact = [UIImage imageWithData:(__bridge NSData *)ABPersonCopyImageData(person)];`?

Comment: `UIImage`, as declared.

Comment: But somewhere this has to be set so an instance of `UIImageView`. Try to search for the name to find all code which is accessing it.

Comment: The only matches are those written in the question text.

Comment: Sorry, then I have no explanation for that behavior. Haven't seen that kind of thing.